# Notation for specifying transformation rules

Tags: scoping

I would like to have a compact notation for specifying conditions and results in transformation rules.

Consider `ReplaceAll`:

```
r=ReplaceAll;

r[1, x_/;x>0:>-x]
 (* -1 *)
```

I'd like to avoid writing `x_/;` and `:>`. Here is what I came up with:

```
Clear[f];
Attributes[f] = {HoldRest};
f[val_,cond_,res_] := val /. x_ /; cond :> res
```

I could only get it to work thus,

```
f[1, x$>0, -x$]
 (* -1 *)
```

That expression may not even be robust, because I'm not sure that the pattern always gets renamed `x$`. But what I'm really after is a notation like this:

```
f[1, x>0, -x]
```

without the `$` on the `x`. It should work even if `x` is defined (hence the `HoldRest` `Attribute`): for this purpose `x` should be interpreted simply as a notational convenience.

How can we do this?

My motivation is now one of curiosity, to get a better understanding of how scoping works inside patterns. Initially I was setting up conditions on a problem, for which many different replacement rules were to be used on the same expression, and I was looking for ways to simplify the notation so as not to keep writing  `/.`, `x_/;`, and `:>`.

Comment: Actually, in this particular case, renaming does the right thing for you, making the rule invariant over the pattern variable. Usually, fighting the renaming mechanism is a last resort, useful in some narrow set of cases (usually related to run-time code generation). Often, the need to do it indicates a bad design. You can defeat renaming, but what you get here is a broken function, which only works if you supply literally "x" (and not any other variable). To me, this new function `f` looks like an invitation for trouble.

Comment: A recent vote reminded me of this question.  As a matter of personal curiosity, why did you Accept Rojo's answer over mine?  Using `#` still seems a more natural syntax to me, but perhaps I've overlooked something?

Comment: @Leonid since you always bring a deeper perspective: what do you think of my proposal?

Comment: @Mr Rojo provided considerable insight into the scoping issue in this context, which satisfied my personal curiosity. ;) I do agree that the slot mechanism is a natural choice in general.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It is probably ok to do this, but I personally would not probably do this because it may be confusing - by looking at such code (after a while or written by someone else), I would most definitely think that the ampersand was forgotten. Your suggestion is more along the macro-writing ideology, but then I'd write macros consistently. Mathematica does not currently provide the right support for them, although in principle it can be implemented from within Mathematica. Something I was also thinking about :)

Comment: @JxB That's perfectly reasonable.  I agree Rojo's answer is far more complete.

Comment: @Leonid thanks as always for your perspective.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Not much to thank for :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not an expert on scoping constructs... Replacement rules aren't very respectful of inner scoping constructs, of the expression in which they are replacing. They seem to be respectful however of the scoping constructs of the expression they are building.

So, for example

```
Hold[val /. x_ /; cond :> res] /. cond :> x
```

returns

```
Hold[val /. x_ /; x :> res]
```

but, like your example

```
{1, x>0, -x}/.{val_,cond_,res_}:>(val/. x_/;cond:>res)
```

returns

```
1/. x$_/;x>0:>-x
```

In any case, we need to avoid the rescoping. Many ways to do this, but one would be to simply prevent the replacer to see your `x_` as a scoped variable when it does the replacing

```
Attributes[f] = {HoldRest};
f[val_, cond_, res_] := val /. Pattern @@ Hold[x, _] /; cond :> res
```

In place of `Pattern @@ Hold[x, _]` you can put anything that evaluates to x_ without having it explicitly. You coudl make your own function, write `Pattern[x, Sequence[], _]`, `Union@Pattern[x, _, _]`, `Identity[Pattern][x, _]`, `Evaluate[Pattern][x, _]`, `Reverse[Pattern[_, x]]`, `ToExpression["x_"]`, `Pattern @@ (x _)` (notice the space, could be a +). In those cases that don't hold its arguments, however, you would need to add an `Unevaluated` to avoid problems if `x` is defined

@WReach's good suggestions in the comments are based on this too, on hiding the `x_` as a scoped variable when the replacement is done, by injecting them later

*Edit*

Things like `Pattern[x, 1 _^1+0]` or stuff like that with the same structure (head `Pattern`2 arguments, won't work because it recognises it as a pattern)

Ok, I said there are many ways, so I'll give another example... Another way to implement the above is to lexically scope your Pattern so it isn't a pattern but you can type it as such. It probably only makes sense if your rhs is big and the lhs is small, but it also has the advantage of working when the pattern is inside held constructs. By the way, I never saw this done so I reserve the right to be suggesting something stupid and abstruse. In any case, its instructive and you wanted to learn, hehe

```
Attributes[f] = {HoldRest};
With[{rp = Pattern}, Module[{Pattern},
  f[rp[val, _], rp[cond, _], rp[res, _]] := Unevaluated@
     (val /. x_ /; cond :> res)
    /. Pattern :> rp]]
```

So, when you write your code, you can use `x_` as you wish, because it will be interpreted as some `Pattern$ASk` that's not a scoping contruct. You use `rp` for those that you wish to become real patterns at definition time and _ those who you want to turn into patterns at execution time.

Another idea is, instead of hiding the scoping variable, hide the scoping constructs until runtime

```
Attributes[f] = {HoldRest};
With[{Condition = Hold[Condition], RuleDelayed = Hold[RuleDelayed], 
  ReplaceAll = Hold[ReplaceAll]},
 SetDelayed @@ 
  Hold[f[val_, cond_, res_], ReleaseHold[val /. x_ /; cond :> res]]
 ]
```

In order for the `With` to work you need to do something like that `SetDelayed@@` because that's another scoping construct that `With` won't go into willingly. So, in this example, you see two layers of the trick.

Comment: This is great, thanks!

Comment: A couple more alternatives along the suggested lines: `f[val_,cond_,res_] := With[{x = x_}, val /. x /; cond :> res]` or `f[val_,cond_,res_] := val /. # /; cond :> res &@ x_`.

Answer (score 8):

How about using `Slot` (#)?

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldRest]

f[expr_, cond_, rep_] := expr /. x_?(cond &) :> (rep &)[x]

f[{0, 1, 2}, # > 0, -#]
```

> ```
> {0, -1, -2}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it is not elegant:

```
Clear[f1];
Attributes[f1] = {HoldRest};
f1[val_, cond_, res_] := val /. y_ /; (Block[{x}, cond /. x :> #1] &)[
 y] :> (Block[{x}, res /. x :> #1] &)[y]

f1[1, x > 0, -x]
 (* -1 *)
```

Scaling this to many pattern variables is not pretty.